# Glassfish 3 unable to deactivate SSL3 for IIOP

Tags: security, ssl, glassfish, poodle

I'm running Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and want to disable SSL3 for the IIOP ports (default 3820 and 3920).
I set

```
configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL.ssl.ssl3-enabled=false
configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL_MUTUALAUTH.ssl.ssl3-enabled=false
```

and restarted the domain, but

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:3820 -ssl3
```

still connects using SSL3. What am I missing? I did the equivalent for port 8181 and it works (does not accept SSL3 connections):

```
configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.ssl3-enabled=false
```

Comment: Have you double checked to make sure the command has worked properly for IIOP? You can check in the Admin Console or in the `domain.xml`, there are details in this blog http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/11/disabling-sslv3-in-glassfish-41.html

Comment: yes, I did check the Admin Console (SSL3 is unchecked) and domain.xml